# Laptop keeps getting BSOD caused by the wifi adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-11, bsod, network-adapter

So this started 10 days ago where the wifi icon would disappear then usually appear automatically or going to device manager to enable it and would happen once ever couple of days but then since 4 days ago it said no internet and would show no wifi connections when i try opening device manager it would freeze and then i get a BSOD which started happening more often every day i tried many tutorials to fix it but nothing i cant fully recall but in the BSOD it said something about power supply or something familiar hopefuly i can capture it next time and somethimee it says mtwl6ex failed which is the same driver its Mediatek Mt7921 Wifi 6 wireless adapter and my laptop is acer aspire 7 A715

Comment: Please reword your post using commas, points and end-of-paragraphs to make it more readable.

Comment: Remove the adapter in Device Manager, restart and let Windows reinstall the adapter.